# 2 Strings into 1 byte array

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I need to know how to convert two strings into a single byte array. For example, I need to take two numeric values using two `Edittext` where one is 850011 and another is 1005.

I need to put this into a single byte array so that byte array will automatically become something like below if I do it manually:

```
byte[] data = new byte[5];
data[0]=(byte)0x85;
data[1]=(byte)0x00;
data[2]=(byte)0x11;
data[3]=(byte)0x10;
data[4]=(byte)0x05;
```

How to do it foolproof?

Comment: What should happen if the strings are not of even length? E.g. if inputs are `"85011"` and `"105"`, should the resultant hex bytes be `85 01 11 05` or `08 50 11 01 05`? --- If the strings have leading zeroes, should they be retained? E.g. if inputs are `"0000850011"` and `"00001005"`, should the resultant hex bytes be `85 00 11 10 05` or `00 00 85 00 11 00 00 10 05`?

Comment: Should the conversion to byte array happen after strings are appended, or before it?

Comment: the first input always 6 digits and second always 4 digits. yes, zeros should be retained too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using something like:

```
public  byte[] convert(String a, String b) {
   int radix = 16; //for hexadecimal conversion
   //int radix = 10; //for decimal conversion

    String str = a + b;
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        int index = i * 2;
        int j = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 2), radix);
        result[i] = (byte) j;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: if i am printiing  byte[] data = new byte[5];
                    data[0]=(byte)0x86;
                    data[1]=(byte)0x50;
                    data[2]=(byte)0x00;
                    data[3]=(byte)0x10;
                    data[4]=(byte)0x01;
i am getting data = [ -122, 80, 0, 16, 1] 
but if i am giving 2 strings 865000 and 1001 in your method i am getting 
result = [ 86, 50, 0, 10, 1]

Comment: The conversion depends on which base you use, whether decimal or hexadecimal. See modified code.